# Caching dynamic REST content in Cherokee

Tags: caching, php, cherokee, restler

I'm developing a backend server for a mobile app using Cherokee + PHP-FPM + MySQL. I'm providing a RESTful API using Luracast Restler 2.
How do you cache dynamic content so that, for example, once a client has requested a list of items through the REST API, this list (in JSON format) is cached for every other client request until the content validity is set to expire? A global cache mechanism for all clients?

Answer (score 0):

Restler 3 final release will have server side caching support built in the framework itself. Currently you have to implement it on your own within the api method